# why dividing by a scalar in numpy (pylab) return zero (within a script)?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

When I run the following inside a script:

```
from pylab import *
N_rec = 1000
pt = 0.1
bitstrm = rand(N_rec,1)
bitstrm = (bitstrm<=pt)
hist_strm = histogram(bitstrm,  2)
p_strm = (hist_strm[0])/sum(hist_strm[0]) 
print p_strm
```

I get `[0 0]`

However, doing it on the console will return the right answer:
`[ 0.913  0.087]`

what am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are dividing a integer array, you have to previously converted it to float:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N_rec = 1000
>>> pt = 0.1
>>> bitstrm = rand(N_rec,1)
>>> bitstrm = (bitstrm<=pt)
>>> hist_strm = histogram(bitstrm,  2)
>>> p_strm = (hist_strm[0]).astype(np.float)/sum(hist_strm[0]) 
>>> print p_strm
[ 0.894  0.106]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Some follow up question then:
1. Do you know why was it successful when I did it on the console?

Comment: I have the same error when I use the console, are you sure that you get the correct result when doing it from console?

Comment: Also, another follow up question: The documentation doesn't say that histogram() returns an integer (it doesn't specify any return type). Do you know how can I know the type of the returned variable? 

Quoting the doc: "hist : array
The values of the histogram. See normed and weights for a description of the possible semantics."

Comment: A simple way to know the type of any numpy variable is printing it: `print variable.dtype`

Comment: Yes and no..
It works fine on the Spyder console. (i just opened a new console to make sure). But when i tried now it on the IPython console, it reproduces the error

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python. trying to do some porting from MATLAB.. Not very easy though because i 'speak' MATLAB. so my head can be available for thinking on 'what' i want to do. yet in python i am stuck on the 'how'.I am making my first baby steps here. So hopefully I'll be able to speak python as well.I think I mostly get stuck on syntax issues (like above). Can you recommend any tutorial for MATLAB speakers? The net is full with tutorials, but most of them are not concise for MATLAB speakers: Describing all the potential pitfalls.

Comment: Not extensive, but helpful is this link http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users, for everything else SO :)

Comment: By the way, 
when I type: print hist_strm[1].dtype
I get float64. So I don't understand the reason for the first issue.
When I type: print hist_strm.dtype
I get an error (can't print types of arrays?)

Comment: @user2476373 I guess the different result on the console is caused by different Python versions. In Python 3 the division shows different behaviour. In older versions the result of dividing two integers is again an integer, in Python 3 the result is always a float. If you want the same behaviour in Python 2.x, you can use `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @user2476373 The function `histogram()` returns a tuple `(hist, bin_edges)`. You see that it's a tuple with `type(hist_strm)`. That's why `hist_strm.dtype` doesn't work. You should call the function like in the example in the docs: `hist_strm, bin_edges = np.histogram(bitstrm, 2)`. Then you get two NumPy arrays where you can do `hist_strm.dtype` and `bin_edges.dtype`.